Go with Gin framework: bind json body in middleware AND in handler
I am a new user of GoLang.. I work on a REST API using the framework Gin.
Coming from PHP, I like using the middlewares.
What I want to do, is to check if the body contains a specific key "company_id" and if it does exist, I want to fetch the company from the database and pass it to the handler.
In the handler I want also to get the json body again and bind it to a struct.
The problem is that after binding the request in the middleware, it comes to the handler empty.
Is there any way to get something from the request without wiping it?
I tried different approaches but none is working.
Here is my last try:
middlware.go
type RequestWithCompany struct {
    CompanyId string `json:"company_id"`
}
func LoadCompany() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(context *gin.Context) {
        var requestBody RequestWithCompany
        if err := decodeWithCopy(context, &requestBody); err != nil {
            context.Next()
        }

        companyId = requestBody.CompanyId
        var company = companyModel.Company{}
        company, err := company.GetOneCompanyById(requestBody.CompanyId)
        if err != nil {
            context.Next()
        }
        context.Set("company", company)
        context.Next()
    }
}

I also tried with io.ReadAll()
Any idea how to do it?

The body may be larger than what you can store in memory easily, which is why it's a read-once stream, so I guess you're out of luck. Apart from fetching the company in the handler, you could also pass the parsed JSON body to the handler, as you attempted with the company.

The body is small, a json array of 5 items

Yes, but that doesn't change the code. Also, the code can't know how large it is before it actually reads it.
